# Want to merge two line with same keys but different values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have a javascript string array of tokens to be processed by nodejs to change the output. Need to merge the values of the same string prefix.

What I have:

```
[
"$button-primary-font-color-default: ('light':#000);",
"$button-primary-font-color-default: ('dark':#fff);"
]
```

What I want:

```
["$button-primary-font-color-default: ('light':#000, 'dark':#fff);"]
```

I have tried array.filter with no success. I´m not so good with regular expressions.

Thank you for any help with this.

Comment: _"I have tried..."_ - You forgot to post that attempt...

Comment: _"I have tried array.filter,,,"_, _"I'm not so good with regular expressions"_ - What's the connection between those two topics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping by property name using `reduce` method. Then flatenning the solution into the required format. This is similar to other answers, only a little more generic with the properties.

```js
var input = [
  "$button-primary-font-color-default: ('light':#000);",
  "$button-primary-font-color-default: ('dark':#fff);",
  "$button-secondary-font-color-default: ('secondary':red);"
];


var step1 = input.reduce(function(agg, line) {
  var prop = line.slice(0, line.indexOf(':')).trim();
  var value = line.slice(line.indexOf(':') + 1, line.indexOf(';')).trim().slice(1, -1);
  agg[prop] = agg[prop] || []
  agg[prop].push(value)
  return agg;
}, {})


var result = Object.entries(step1).map(function([prop,value]) {
  return prop + " " + "(" + value.join(", ") + ")";
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I create an object to group each key with array of it's values, for example.

```
{
   "$button-primary-font-color-default:": ["'light':#000", "'dark':#fff"]
}
```

Then I `map`ed the object to be as string format.

```js
const data = [
"$button-primary-font-color-default: ('light':#000);",
"$button-primary-font-color-default: ('dark':#fff);"
]


const obj = data.reduce((acc, i) => {
  const [_, key, value] = i.match(/(\$.*?:)\s\(('\w+':\s?.+?)\);/i)
  acc[key] ? (acc[key] = [...acc[key], value]) : acc[key] = [value]
  return acc
}, {})


const result = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => {
  return `${key} (${value.join(', ')})`
})

console.log(result)
```